# IOS7 Google Maps API Reverse Geocoding xCode

Tags: xcode, google-maps, ios7, core-location, reverse-geocoding

I have a project that uses Apple's "CoreLocation" framework for reverse geocoding. 
How can I make it use Google's "GoogleMaps" framework ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You need to tell us what you have tried. We cannot just feed you answers.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using GoogleApsis directly via an HTTP Connection you handle yourself via [NSURLConnection]

```
"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&sensor=false"
```

Or you can use the Google Maps API [for iOS located here.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/)